Dealing with image path when deploying static nextjs page to github page
When deploying my nextjs static app to github page, the images not shown because the image URL referenced to https://mygithub.github.io/images/image1.jpg instead of https://mygithub.github.io/repo-name/images/image1.jpg.
How to deal with it?
